# Download logs from docker containers

Tags: logging, docker

I'm trying to download logs files from docker containers installed on a Rancher platform. These logs are actually shared with a logstash container for Kibana to use but I would also need the raw log files to be locally downloadable or to be sent to a remote server for instance.

Any suggestion on how this can be done ? Is Rsyslog a good option for instance ?

I'm brand new to the topic, don't hesitate to be specific... :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have the option to attach the output of the container to your host machine

*docker attach --no-stdin=true --sig-proxy=false*

then you can use this to send this to a file using cat

Answer (score 1):

It may be late to answer this question , but for future views may be helpful .
I have some logs file in container and  I have  access  only to the container command line . **so I upload them to some s3 storage**(minio). here is python script,
you should provide your s3 storage settings.

```
from minio import Minio

client = Minio(
        "myminio.host",
        access_key="some",
        secret_key="some",
    )  
    
client.fput_object(
        "bucket_name", "file_name", "filename_in_container.log",
    )
```